# ¿Problema para guardar datos en la bbdd con array?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

#Estimados tengo un error al momento de guardar estos datos en mi bbdd. Este es mi primer error que aparece esto me muestra la consola. Array to string conversion in. Todos los datos son array son mas de un dato

```
$fecha_anterior_kilometraje_tracto=$_POST['fecha_kilometraje'];
$km_anterior_tracto=$_POST['kilometraje_actual'];
$km_actual_tracto=$_POST['kmactual'];
$fecha_km_tracto=$_POST['fecha_ingreso_km'];
$calculo_km_tracto=$_POST['diferencia_km'];

$stmt = $base->prepare("INSERT INTO detalle_kilometraje('fecha_anterior_kilometraje','km_anterior','fecha_km_actual','km_actual','diferencia_km') VALUES (:fecha_anterior,:km_ant,:fecha_km_actual,:km_actual,:diferencia_km)");

$stmt->bindParam(':fecha_anterior',$fecha_anterior_kilometraje_tracto);
$stmt->bindParam(':km_ant',$km_anterior_tracto);
$stmt->bindParam(':fecha_km_actual',$km_actual_tracto);
$stmt->bindParam(':km_actual',$fecha_km_tracto);
$stmt->bindParam(':diferencia_km',$calculo_km_tracto);

foreach ($_POST['fecha_kilometraje'] as $fecha_anterior_kilometraje_tracto) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si todos los elementos son **array** y **todos tienen el mismo número de elementos** y **se relacionan correctamente por su posición en los array** entonces prueba con esto:

```php
$stmt = $base->prepare("INSERT INTO `detalle_kilometraje` (`fecha_anterior_kilometraje`,`km_anterior`,`fecha_km_actual`,`km_actual`,`diferencia_km`) VALUES (:fecha_anterior,:km_ant,:fecha_km_actual,:km_actual,:diferencia_km)");

for ($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['fecha_kilometraje']); i++) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_anterior',  $_POST['fecha_kilometraje'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':km_ant',          $_POST['kilometraje_actual'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_km_actual', $_POST['kmactual'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':km_actual',       $_POST['fecha_ingreso_km'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':diferencia_km',   $_POST['diferencia_km'][$i]);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

### **Explicación**

- Establecemos la consulta `prepare` antes del bucle, pues no hace falta ponerla dentro cada vez.
- El bucle hará tantos ciclos como elementos tenga cualquiera de sus array, y en este caso escojemos el primero, $_POST['fecha_kilometraje'].
- No hace falta preasignar los POST a variables, por lo tanto las he eliminado y he pasado a usar los $POST de este modo:

```
    $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_anterior',$_POST['fecha_kilometraje'][$i]);
```

para que de esta forma, acceda a cada elemento de cada array mediante su número de índice, representado por $i, y así en cada ciclo, hasta el final.

**Nota IMPORTANTE**:  Hay que estar muy seguros de que todas los arrays del POST contienen los mismos elementos **siempre** y que todos se corresponden con el mismo número de índice entre sí **siempre**. De lo contrario podrian producirse facilmente errores de ejecución o de inserción y habria que recodificarlo todo de otra forma, incluido el formulario de donde provenga.

Comment: estimado ahora si funciona :) muchas gracias por su tiempo. Bendiciones

Comment: voy a revertir la pregunta hasta la original, pues ahora no se entiende mi respuesta con tu pregunta actual